# ubuntu 12.04 SSL handshake failed

Tags: ubuntu, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-12.04

Hello I didn't want to install ubuntu 12.04 beta because it has some SSL problems. In 11.04 also have the same problem but it has a easy fix that is this one:

1. sudo apt-get install libneon27

   1. cd /usr/lib
   2. sudo rm libneon-gnutls.so.27
   3. and create a soft link 
      sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libneon.so.27 libneon-gnutls.so.27

So I just install Ubuntu 12.04 final in a VM to see if this bug was fixed but I see that not. Does someone have any idea of how to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

After quite some googling it turned out that there is a bug in the version of libneon bundled with Precise that causes this problem. Fortunately this is already fixed with version 0.29.3. To get back to a working subversion perform these steps:

1. Uninstall the current libneon package:  sudo apt-get remove
   libneon27>
2. Download the latest libneon package
   http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/libneon27  (at the bottom you can
   choose the right version for your architecture).
3. Install the required libssl dependency: sudo apt-get install
   libssl0.9.8 Install the downloaded libneon package. E.g. for the
   64Bit architecture: dpkg -i libneon27_0.29.3-3_amd64.deb
4. Change the symbolic links again like described above: sudo mv
   /usr/lib/libneon-gnutls.so.27
       /usr/lib/libneon-gnutls.so.27.old sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libneon.so.27
       /usr/lib/libneon-gnutls.so.27

([source](http://www.yeap.de/blog2.0/archives/260-Subversion-Certificate-Problems-with-Ubuntu-Precise-Pangolin.html))